# How are the initial boot files found in UEFI

Tags: windows-8, boot, uefi

I was curious and poking around my Windows 8 system.  Per [Wikipedia's entry on UEFI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#UEFIBOOT)

> Boot loaders can also be automatically detected by the UEFI firmware, to enable booting from removable devices. Auto-detection relies on a standardized file path to the operating system loader, depending on the actual architecture to boot. Format of the file path is defined as EFI_SYSTEM_PARTITION/BOOT/BOOTMACHINE_TYPE_SHORT_NAME.EFI, e.g. /efi/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI

I decided to mount my EFI system partition and check it out.

The only remotely relevant file I see is M:\boot\boot.sdi

In M:\boot there is also an en-us (which contains bootsect.exe.mui), fonts, resources folder as well as bcd, etfsboot.exe, and memtest.exe

Since there is no BOOT*.efi how does UEFI know where to find the boot files?  Also the "boot" folder is lower cased and per Wiki it seems it should be "BOOT"

Comment: Are you positive your computer is using UEFI and not legacy support?  Verify your hdd is a GPT disk

Comment: Yes it's booting into UEFI.  I have UEFI enabled in the BIOS.  I'm partitioned GPT and the System partition is designated properly as an EFI SYSTEM PARTITION

Answer (score 1):

On UEFI System Partition paths begin with \EFI !

For example:

```
Z:\EFI\Boot\bootx64.efi

Z:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi

Z:\EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```

"\EFI\Boot" folder/directory stores the default fallback boot loader.

\EFI\'Company' - are also reserved names.

'Company' folder can have any structure (sub, sub-sub folders). The corresponding boot entry has the correct path to boot loader file, e.g. "\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi"

Answer (score 0):

Note that the exact phrase is

> Boot loaders can *also* be automatically detected by the UEFI firmwares

Emphasis mine. Earlier on in that section, it states that:

> The UEFI specification defines a "boot manager", a firmware policy engine that is in charge of loading the operating system loader and all necessary drivers. The boot configuration is controlled by a set of global NVRAM variables, *including boot variables that indicate the 
>   paths to the loaders*.

Again, emphasis mine. The EFI "BIOS" knows where the correct loader is because Windows, during installation, told it where to look and it is evidently in a different location than the default.