# Which UEFI executables get auto-detected?

Tags: boot, uefi, firmware

According to [this phenomenal overview of UEFI](https://www.happyassassin.net/2014/01/25/uefi-boot-how-does-that-actually-work-then/), there are 3 types of UEFI entries:

- **Compatibility-boot** will boot whatever is at the beginning of the disk, like BIOS did
- **Native-boot** will boot an EFI executable from an explicit path
- **Fallback-boot** will boot an EFI executable from various default locations (based on architecture, `/EFI/BOOT/BOOTx64.efi`, `/EFI/BOOT/BOOTaa64.efi`, etc.)

All this makes sense, but when I look at an EFI System Partition from an OS (CentOS, in this case) there are many more `.efi` files.

```
+--EFI
|  +--boot
|  |  +--BOOTAA64.EFI
|  |  \--fallback.efi
|  +--centos
|  |  +--gcdaa64.efi
|  |  +--grubaa64.efi
|  |  +--MokManager.efi
|  |  +--shim-centos.efi
|  |  \--shim.efi
```

Additionally, the boot manager only lists an option to boot `/EFI/centos/shim.efi`. This CentOS disk came from another computer, so the firmware on this machine never had an explicit entry added for `shim.efi`.

Why are there so many `.efi` files?

How did the boot manager find `shim.efi`?

Why didn't the boot manager find all the other `.efi` files?

*[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/697419/how-are-the-initial-boot-files-found-in-uefi) is similar, but is more about the distinction between fallback and native booting.*

Comment: "How did the boot manager find shim.efi?" - I would imagine it just looks in the /EFi/* path and presents the EFI drivers it finds.  So `gcdaa64` is related to Grub it appears.  MokManager is releated to managing your keys, used by secure boot, and used by Shim.  "Why are there so many .efi files?" - They were all required in order for CentOS to boot on the older machine.

Comment: @Ramhound, thanks for the input - what I don't understand is why ONLY shim.efi shows up in the boot manager when all these files are on the system. For instance, it finds shim.efi, but doesn't find shim-centos.efi.

Comment: It likely connected to the fact the HDD is from another system but see Rod's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why are there so many `.efi` files?

Most of these files are support files. For instance, MokManager is a tool for managing Machine Owner Keys (MOKs), which are used by Shim to expand the number of Secure Boot keys that the computer recognizes. MokManager is typically called if Shim can't launch its default follow-on boot loader (typically GRUB). It looks like you've got at least two copies of Shim in `EFI/centos` (`shim.efi` and `shim-centos.efi`), and `EFI/boot/BOOTAA64.EFI` is probably a third copy of Shim. Chances are one of those in `EFI/centos` is redundant -- perhaps left over from a previous installation that used a different name or created by accident.

Linux developers have also gotten into the habit of creating new EFI program files to work around problems or special-case issues. For instance, your installation shows two copies of GRUB in the `EFI/centos` directory -- `grubaa64.efi` and `gcdaa64.efi` are identical except for where they look for their configuration and support files. (See [this Stack Exchange question and answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/195128/whats-the-difference-between-grubx64-efiand-gcdx64-efi) for slightly more on this issue.)

> How did the boot manager find `shim.efi`?

You've already (partially) answered that question -- in what you called "native-boot," the computer stores a path to the boot loader in an NVRAM variable. Most Linux distributions these days use Shim by default, so the NVRAM variable will point to a Shim binary. When Shim launches, it will register itself with the firmware and then launch a follow-on boot loader (normally GRUB).

> Why didn't the boot manager find all the other .efi files?

A standard EFI boot manager does not actively scan for `.efi` files, except for the fallback filename and, in some EFI's, Microsoft's boot loader. (There are others that might be added to the boot list in some cases, such as network boot entries and entries for a built-in EFI shell.)

Instead, most EFIs rely on the OS installer to register a boot loader as part of the boot loader installation process. Thus, CentOS will write Shim, GRUB, and related `.efi` binaries to the ESP, and then add one or more NVRAM entries to point to them. In theory, an OS could store ten, a hundred, a thousand, or more `.efi` files on the ESP and register just one of them. When you reboot and hit whatever keystroke is necessary to enter the EFI boot manager, you'll see just the one entry that the OS installer added. You can add, delete, or edit these entries with the `efibootmgr` tool in most Linux distributions.

AFAIK, the only tools that actively scan for EFI boot loaders are:

- **[rEFIt](http://refit.sourceforge.net/)** -- This old boot manager was used mainly on Macs, but it can be used on UEFI-based PCs. It actively scans for boot loaders in most subdirectories of `EFI` (that is, `EFI/centos/`, `EFI/BOOT/`, etc.), `EFI/tools/` being a notable exception. Note that rEFIt is no longer being maintained.
- **[rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/)** -- This is my updated fork of rEFIt, and it inherits rEFIt's active-scanning algorithm, with some tweaks to make it work better with Linux and to explicitly trim redundant or otherwise unnecessary boot entries. Thus, rEFInd shows both `.efi` binaries and Linux kernels (which in most cases are EFI program files, thanks to the [EFI stub loader](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/efi-stub.txt)).
- **GRUB 2's configuration scripts** -- Distributions that rely on GRUB 2 typically ship with scripts that scan for `.efi` files and add them to the GRUB menu. Unlike rEFIt and rEFInd, though, these scans occur when Linux (or some other host OS) is running, not at boot time.

Note that none of these tools affect what appears in the EFI's own boot manager menu; they all affect what appears in their own menus, nothing more. In theory, other tools might perform such scans. An EFI *could* do such scans, either at every boot or upon command from the user, but in practice I don't know of any that do; AFAIK, all EFIs rely on their own boot managers with associated NVRAM entries. (Some are buggy, which makes those NVRAM entries are unreliable, thus making use of the fallback filename a practical necessity.)

Comment: Rod, thanks for such a detailed answer! It's really helped more with my UEFI understanding. Regarding shim.efi in particular, I discovered (through some console logs) that this UEFI implementation has a list of ~10 hard-coded executable paths it looks for, including centos/shim.efi. Clever name for your fork btw :)